# getting error that .include() is not a function, even though i passed an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function

I am trying to write a middleware that checks if the user that is trying to retrieve the data of all users is an admin or not, for testing purpose I have manually passed an array to isAuthorized function.

```js
userRouter.use(isAuthorized(['admin']));
userRouter
.route('/')
.get(getAllUsers);
```

The isAuthorized function goes as follows:

```js
module.exports.isAuthorized = function isAuthorized(roles) { 
    return function(req,res,next) {
        try{
            if(roles.include('admin')) {
                next();
            }
            else {
                res.status(401).json({
                    message:"User not authorized"
                });
            }
        }
        catch(error) {
            return res.json({
                message: error.message
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error :
roles.include is not a function

Please Help!!

I tried googling same error and looked up previously posted solutions on stackoverflow and other websies, but none of them worked.

Comment: looks like you mistyped [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: just do a `roles.includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if admin is part of your schema,you can just check if isAdmin is in the request body

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.isAdmin ) {
        return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Sorry, you need admin access for this route" })
      }
      next()

};
```

then in your route

```
const isAdmin = require("../middelwares");

userRouter.use(isAdmin);
userRouter
.route('/')
.get(getAllUsers);
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct name of the method you are trying to call is `.includes()`. You may want to look up the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for array methods to make sure you're using the correct method and to look up any unclear behaviour.